# $n^x$, $x$ is irrational number what is the result?

Tags: number-theory

if for a real number $n$ , $n^x$ where $x$ is an irrational number. What is nature of number $n^x$ ? Possible values or how to determine nature of number $n^x$ ?

value of square root of 2 rays to square root of 2.

Comment: Do you mean $n$ to be an arbitrary real, or did you mean for it to be a (positive) integer?

Comment: $n^x=\exp(\ln(n)x)$

Comment: what is the nature which group it belongs rational or irratnal number ?

Comment: The number $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is known to be trancendental by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_theorem), which answered [Hilbert's seventh problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_seventh_problem).

Comment: describe in detail about Gelfond-Schneidertheorem as well as hilbert's seventh problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an engaging theorem that says that there exist two irrational numbers $x,y$ such that $x^y$ is rational.

The engaging part is the proof:

Consider $x=\sqrt 2^\sqrt 2$. If $x$ is rational the theorem is proved. If not, $x^\sqrt 2=2$, and the theorem is proved.